# Adding up numbers in a column in Python doesn't work properly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have a dataframe (called df) that currently looks like this:

```
    Date    Amount
01/11/2019  -0.4
01/11/2019  -15.81
01/11/2019  -21.98
31/10/2019  -5.27
30/10/2019  -1.5
30/10/2019  -20
30/10/2019  -5,000
```

I would like to sum the column "Amount" up. To do so, I have taken the following steps:

```
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].str.replace(',', '')
pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'])
df['Amount'].sum()
```

However, when I try to sum it, I get a string, even though the column "Amount" is clearly a float:

```
'-0.4-15.81-21.98-5.27-1.5-20-5000'
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to solve this? I've been stuck on this for a while!

Thank you!

Comment: You didn't assign it back, use: `df['Amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'])` in your second row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, only need to change this line:

```
df['Amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use direct sum operation of what pandas offer. Axis is showing column index.

```py
df.sum(axis = 1, skipna = True)
```

`skipna`is for skip NaN columns.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'])`, it converts the column 'Amount' to numeric, but does not replace the values in the actual column. The modified (or converted) column is stored in the '_' variable.

You need to include `df['Amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'])` to replace the actual column in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a `thousand` argument that can help you convert all the values into numeric. see a mockup below. Let me know if it works.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
Mydata = StringIO("""Date  Amount
01/11/2019  -0.4
01/11/2019  -15.81
01/11/2019  -21.98
31/10/2019  -5.27
30/10/2019  -1.5
30/10/2019  -20
30/10/2019  -5,000
    """)

df = pd.read_csv(Mydata, sep="  ",engine='python', thousands=',')

df
```

result below:

```
Date    Amount
0   01/11/2019  -0.40
1   01/11/2019  -15.81
2   01/11/2019  -21.98
3   31/10/2019  -5.27
4   30/10/2019  -1.50
5   30/10/2019  -20.00
6   30/10/2019  -5000.00
```